# Return Employee name based on column/table?

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
SELECT C.CustomerID,
       C.Name, 
       BL.LocationCity,
       ST.DealerShipToID,
       RC.Name 'ShipToName',
       isnull(e.Name, c.SalesRepID),
       ...
   FROM Customer C
   JOIN ShipTo ST on ST.ShiptoID = C.ShipToID
   JOIN Employee E on E.EmployeeID = ST.SalesRepID
```

Above is what I have. I am trying to return the name of the employee if the SalesRepID field is blank in ST.SalesRepID. So if ST.SalesRepID is null, check the Customer table for the sales rep ID and return the name. Right now, it is only returning the name of the employee if the SalesRepID field inside the Shipto isn't null. It returns the EmployeeID if it is null.

Customer Table:

```
|CustomerID|SalesRepID|ShipToID|
|----------|----------|--------|
|00000     |11111     |11111   |
|00001     |21111     |11112   |
|00002     |31111     |11113   |
|00003     |41111     |11114   |
|00004     |51111     |11115   |
```

ShipTo Table:

```
|CustomerID|SalesRepID|ShipToID|
|----------|----------|--------|
|00000     |11111     |11111   |
|00001     |21111     |11112   |
|00002     |null      |11113   |
|00003     |41111     |11114   |
|00004     |51111     |11115   |
```

Employee Table:

```
|EmployeeID|EmployeeName   |
|----------|---------------|
|11111     |Jay Cutler     |
|21111     |Brett Farve    |
|31111     |Tom Brady      |
|41111     |Patrick Mahomes|
|51111     |Drew Brees     |
```

Right now it returns

```
|CustomerID/Name|ShipToName|EmployeeName|
|---------------|----------|------------|
|00000          |11111     |Jay Cutler  |
|00001          |21111     |Brett Farve |
|00002          |31111     |**11113**   |
|00003          |41111     |Patrick M.  |
|00004          |51111     |Drew Brees  |
```

I want it to return

```
|CustomerID/Name|ShipToName|EmployeeName|
|---------------|----------|------------|
|00000          |11111     |Jay Cutler  |
|00001          |21111     |Brett Farve |
|00002          |31111     |Tom Brady   |
|00003          |41111     |Patrick M.  |
|00004          |51111     |Drew Brees  |
```

Comment: Can you please add some sample data? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @DaminiSuthar I added the sample tables. It shows up correctly in edit but when I post it, it just shows it as how I typed. Not sure how to fix, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE()` or `ISNULL()` or even `CASE` expression to check for `NULL` value in `ST.SalesRepID` and use `C.SalesRepID` instead

```
INNER JOIN Employee E on E.EmployeeID = COALESCE(ST.SalesRepID, C.SalesRepID)
```